# Filter before show the ng-table

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have a search engine that leads to another page with Ng-table .
Is it possible to bring the values ​​of the previous search engine to filter ng-table.

(I got the params from `$routeparams` in the second page with ng-table)
I want to bring straight that search with the appropriate value in the appropriate field

Image:
this search engine in the first page:

[image]

second page with ng-table.

[image]

Comment: Please tag `ngtable` and not `table`

Comment: Why not forward these params to the new route?

Comment: i forward the params, and i got the params in the second page( with the ng-table). my question: if i search "הכנרת והסביבה" and clicked search, il farward to the ng-table page and see in the "מיקום" field "הכנרת והסביבה" without write it there.

Comment: o.k i make it work with filter easly, thanks alot.